# Asynchronous postback when click on a treenode in master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, treeview

I am using ASP.NET MVC to build my application. I have a treeview (with treenodes having hrefs) in the masterpage and when click on the treenode corresponding page get loaded in the content view. I need this to happen asynchronously. Also I need to persist the state of the tree(i.e. expand / collapse of each nodes) after each node click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with regards to activating a click event on an element you need to either know its id or class name.

so to activatea click event on an element with a class of "treeNode" use;

```
$(".treeNode").click(function(){

//your code here.

});
```

to do a postback to a controller actionresult, use;

```
$.post('/Controller/Action', { param1: paramValue }, function (retHTML) {
  //code here on success
});
```

retHTML above is what is returned from the ajax post.

in your controller do this;

```
public void jQuery_DeleteAttachment(string param1)
{
   //your code here
}
```

I would, from my controller, i would return a partialview.

```
public void jQuery_DeleteAttachment(string param1)
{
   return PartialView("viewname", model);
}
```

In the jQuery success code I would replace, append, whatever, the retHTML to where I wanted it.